# Затенение фона модального окна Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap

Есть стандартное модальное окно Bootstrap, нужно оставить возможность блокировки контента(data-backdrop="true") но **убрать затенение** с фона **при сохранении возможности закрытия модалки кликом по фону**.

Comment: изменение цвета фона `.modal-backdrop` не подходит?

Comment: При изменении цвета на белый, на контент все равно накладывается белый полупрозрачным фон(если поставить background-color: none это работает как стандартное затенение). Я думал нужно играться с opacity какого то поля и ваша подсказка пришлась кстати.

Answer (score 3):

В `background-color` значения `none` не существует, поэтому  когда вы его задаете, браузер его пропускает и возвращается к предыдущему заданному значению. Возможные значения:

```
background-color: <цвет> | transparent | inherit
```

Поэтому задайте фону значение прозрачность:

```
 .modal-backdrop {
   background-color: transparent;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

За изменение прозрачности отвечает opacity, единственное, изначально не мог найти какой именно елемент отвечает конкретно за фон и его прозрачность(думал .fade-in, но он вызывает сам эффект), следуя подсказке в комментарии:

> изменение цвета фона .modal-backdrop не подходит?

оказалось, что решение проблемы - добавления в сss:

```
.modal-backdrop{opacity: 0 !important;}
```

Или внести изменения в файлы бутстрапа.